# CSS border abbreviation

Tags: css, border, abbreviation

I want to trim my CSS border statement. I know there is a possibility, but I found always that one in the internet e.g. :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would better do it through classes like this:

```css
.box{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 20px;
    float: left;
}    
.border{
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #98bf21;
}
.b1{ border-width: 5px 10px 15px 2px; }
.b2{ border-width: 5px 7px 10px 7px; }
.b3{ border-width: 15px 2px 10px 5px; }
```

```html
<div class="box border b1"></div>
<div class="box border b2"></div>
<div class="box border b3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For for instance padding, you can write: `padding: 5px 10px` to set a five pixel top and bottom padding and a 10 pixel left and right padding.

But for border, that is not the case. You have to set the same value to all sides, or set the property for one side at a time.

You can however set just the width using `border-left-width`, so you could set a default border and override just the width for specific sides:

```
border: 5px solid #666;
border-left-width: 10px;
border-right-width: 10px;
```

Or use `border-width`, which lets you set multiple values for the width alone, in the same way as you can set padding.

Comment: (or `border-width: 5px 10px` instead of the individual `border-left-width` and `border-right-width`)